# image resizing in asp core

Tags: asp.net-core, image-uploading, image-resizing

i need a help from u guys to resizing a image when we uploading

```
 try
                {
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "images");
                    if (files != null)
                    {
                        string ext = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);
                        string folderImageName = "menu_" + menu.menuId + ext;
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, folderImageName), FileMode.Create))
                        {                           
                            await files.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                        menu.image = folderImageName;
                    }
                    _context.Update(menu);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("MenuItemManagement", new { msg = "editSuccess" });
                }
```

these code am using to upload the image

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use ImageSharp (https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp) on .Net Core or ImageProcessor (http://imageprocessor.org/) / ImageResizer (https://imageresizing.net/) on .Net Framework

Simple exaple of use ImageSharp

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("oryginal.jpg"))
using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("resized.jpg"))
{
    Image image = new Image(stream);
    image.Resize(yourWidth, yourHeight)
         .Save(output);
}
```